# I am not able to write on a network drive (Hosted with samba) using a php program. Why?

Tags: permissions, mount, php, samba, chmod

I have a network drive service hosted on Samba(Whose settings I can't change) when I mount it on my ubuntu pc using mount.cifs I am able to read write it's content. To make a directory or file there using sudo only(My current user have sudo rights).

Mount command used is: `sudo mount.cifs //address.to.samba /mnt/temp -o"username=user,password=pswd"`

When the network drive is mounted on /mnt/temp/, in my php program `file_exists(/mnt/temp/)` returns True where as `is_writable(/mnt/temp/)` returns false.

The permission of /mnt/temp is initially 755. But even if I do chmod to 766 for the directory it dosen't change.

what shall I do ?

Comment: You should say how you are running this php, and who you think it is running as. Example: is this phone invoked as part of a web interface.

Comment: @jdv I am running an apache server to host the php and the php is running becouse if I save it elsewhere it works fine and as well as all other things in php gives output

Comment: `-o 'uid=...,gid=...,file_mode=...,dir_mode=...,username=...,password=...'`. See the [manual page for `mount.cifs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you @AlexP It works. only if we set the dir_mode=777.
please write it as a answer it will help others as well.

Comment: @ShaleenJain always [edit] the question when adding requested details. Neither question details nor answers should be hidden in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFS filesystems get their owner and group from parameters of the `mount` command:

```
mount -t cifs -o 'uid=...,gid=...,file_mode=...,dir_mode=...,credentials=...'
```

See the manual page for [`mount`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) for details.

You probably want to mount the filesystem with the uid/gid under which the Apache HTTP server runs.